# How can I ignore encoded characters in a tkinter TextBox?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have an app with a text box which gets input from various sources. I need to be able to save the contents of this text box into a .txt file.

On it's own, this is simple enough:

```
outputFile.write(outputText.get(1.0, "end-1c"))
```

But, just occasionally, the input contains some odd characters. They display in the Text Box okay, but it fails when I try to save it as above, with an error:

> 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\uffa2' in position 1823: character maps to < undefined>

There is no way to know in advance what characters will appear. How can I get around this - either by ignoring all/any odd characters, or converting to 'u'\uffa2' or whatever they are?

Comment: So, can you be a little clear? Do you want help with implementation of either of the two (mentioned in the last paragraph) ? or are you asking which is better?

Comment: @ThePerson: I'm just looking for any way to do it. Implementing either of my two suggestions or something I've not thought of.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you gave us some examples of the type of characters you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked in some situations of this sort, but I am unable to reproduce the same kind of situation. The following solution should work (I am unable to check it though).

```
x=outputText.get()    
for i in x:
    try:
        outputFile.write(i)
    except:
        print("Character", i, "was not accepted")
```

Let me know if this gives an error.

Happy to help!

Comment: Well it depends on what I try and save, but if I run it against a list of currently software on a remote PC, then I get 5 errors, complaining about characters; u\uffa2; u\uffa4; u\uff82; u\xff & u\uff87.

Comment: As I said, I don't know if/when any odd characters may emerge, nor what they might be, so I need a way of 'ignoring' them regardless.

Comment: What the above code does is, it ignores the characters that give an error and accepts the others

Comment: Aha, so it does! That will do nicely! Thanks!